# Import data from multiple MySQL data sources via SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

I have a particularly challenging situation that I could use some assistance with.

I work for a manufacturing facility and am working on a proof of concept. 
I have a number of client devices (PIs) fixed to manufacturing equipment, all collecting data from the equipment and storing this data locally within an embedded MySQL database on the device.  I would like to import the data from each of the devices, into a central Microsoft SQL Data Warehouse.  I would prefer this to be pulled from the devices by the server, rather than being pushed from the client devices.

I would then like the embedded database on the device to be updated / purged, to prevent the same data from being resent (initially I was thinking a date field in a table which I just timestamp once that record has been copied).

My feelings are that a SSIS package would be the way to go here, I have IP addresses and connection information for the PIs in a table within the DW, and so would like to connect to each client in turn to import the data and update it.

Is there a way to change a connection string on the fly within SSIS?  OR would there be a better way to achieve this - maybe via a sproc on the DW?

I'm ok with sprocs, but very new to SSIS.  If you have any links/tutorials/posts that may help, please share.  Thanks.

**EDIT:**  This is what I already have

[image: Execute SQL Task Editor window]

Here are my variables:

[image: Variable List]
As you can see it is showing an error when attempting to run on the first step.

[image: This is what I already have, showing an error]

Also, FWIW, here's the progress output...

[image: SSIS package progress output]

Comment: Use a For each loop with ADO Enumerator with a Dataflow task inside. Look [this tutorial](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/implementing-foreach-looping-logic-in-ssis/) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to change a connection string on the fly within SSIS?

Use a variable to store the connection string, and use that variable to populate the Expression value of the connection string.  Then when you change the value of the variable, you will change the value of the connection string.

Answer (score 1):

Its not the answer but something like this.

A) you create a table all the IP address, and connection strings.
B) SSIS create variables for each property i.e Variable IPAddress.
C) Create Execute SQL Task; Set Full Result set.
     Also Add Result Set: Result Name: 0 Varaible Name Rows.
D) Create another Variable Rows: DataType  System.Object.
E) Add Foreach Loop Container: ADO: Rows
                 Variable Mapping: IPAddress
F) Create Source Connection Manager
    Expression set the connection as of your Variables
G) Add a Data Flow Task and fetch the data from each connection.

Comment: Funnily enough, this (apart from the ADO type container) was what I already have.  Fails at C when I try to run the task (says it's successful but there's an X against the task in the package designer window)

Comment: So in Task C, you should have a SQL Statement "Select IPConnection from Table name" ?

Comment: SQL Statement is "SELECT device_ipaddress FROM Devices WHERE Device_inactive=0", with SQLSourceType as Direct Input.  ResultSet is User::ListOfPIs (which is of type System.Object).  Other Variable is IPAddress, which is of type String,

Comment: Ok, in the General Tab. What is your ResultSet? That needs to be "Full result set"

Comment: Ok perfect, then Result Set tab. Is your "Result Name" = 0 and "Variable Name" = User::ListOfPIs ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178680/discussion-between-adzzzuk-and-mvisser).